# Use a list of variables as patterns in re.sub

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a list of strings as patterns to clean another string using regex. I am attaching the code I wrote:

```
import re

a = ['[^A-Za-z0-9]', 'test', '( {2,})']
string= 'This_is __ the test text i        am trying to ... --- clean!'
for entry in a:
    result = re.sub(entry, "", string)
print (result)
```

The result I get:

```
This_is __ the test text iam trying to ... --- clean!
```

while I wish to get:

```
This is the text i am trying to clean
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `re.sub` returns a new string, not modifying the input. Try to replace `result` with `string` but you will then find some other issues with your code. Right now, you're only applying the last pattern

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `string` after each iteration of the loop. Try something like this

```
for entry in a:
    string = re.sub(entry, "", string)
print(string)
```

Note: You might want to change the first regex since that matches spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from this code

```
for entry in a:
    result = re.sub(entry, "", string)
print (result)
```

What you actually print is the last result from the `for` loop: It will return the result from `'( {2,})'` regex and not all the regexs!

So what you can do is basically:

```
import re

a = ['[^A-Za-z0-9]', 'test', '( {2,})']
string= 'This_is __ the test text i        am trying to ... --- clean!'
for entry in a:
    string = re.sub(entry, "", string)
print(result)
```

Note that you shouldn't use `print (result)` but instead use `print(result)`

Then you will get `This is the text i am trying to clean`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = ['_','[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', 'test', '( {2,})']
string= 'This_is __ the test text i        am trying to ... --- clean!'
for entry in a:
  if entry in ['_','( {2,})']:
    string = re.sub(entry, " ", string)
  else:
    string = re.sub(entry, "", string)
```

This will result in

```
This is the text i am trying to clean
```